# My s6 does not have a USB icon

Tags: usb

Trying to move a photo album from my S6 phone to my HP computer. I asked computer for help and it told me to go to drop down bar on my phone and hit the USB icon. There isn't one there. I went to settings and could not find it there either. All I really want to do is move some photos from my phone to Shutterfly. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I've found AirDroid quite useful fro transferring files PC is on lan, tablets are on Wifi. (My PC doesn't fully recognise the tablets via USB (Debug for Android Studio is fine) but unable to use usb for Windows explorer). You need to install AirDroid on both the PC and on the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need your phone to be connected to your computer
If the icon still doesn't appear, go to settings, storage and after hitting the 3-dot menu you should see a USB mode button